# Finding ranges of continuous values

Tags: mongodb, continuous

I have the following Mongo collection:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "user": "A",
    "comment": "commentA1"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "user": "A",
    "comment": "commentA2"
  },
  {
    "key": 5,
    "user": "A",
    "comment": "commentA5"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "user": "B",
    "comment": "commentB2"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "user": "B",
    "comment": "commentB3"
  },
  {
    "key": 6,
    "user": "B",
    "comment": "commentB6"
  }
]
```

and I need to find the first continuous keys, with no gaps, per user.
So, for user A I should get the first 2 documents, and for user B the first two also.
The collection might contain more than 2M documents, so the query should work fast.

I have found SQL solutions for this problem (http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-gap-analysis-missing-values-sequence.html in section number 3), but I am looking for a Mongo solution.

How can I do it in Mongo 4.0 (DocumentDB) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: according to further elaboration on the comments,

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {key: 1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$user",
      data: {$push: {key: "$key", comment: "$comment"}},
      shadow: {$push: {$add: ["$key", 1]}}
  }},
  {$project: {
      data: 1,
      shadow: {$filter: {input: "$shadow", cond: {$in: ["$$this", "$data.key"]}}}
  }},
  {$project: {data: 1, shadow: 1, firstItem: {$subtract: [{$first: "$shadow"}, 1]}}},
  {$project: {data: 1, firstItem: 1, shadow: {$concatArrays: [["$firstItem"], "$shadow"]}}},
  {$project: {
      data: 1,
      shadow: {$reduce: {
          input: {$range: [0, {$size: "$shadow"}]},
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$eq: [
                      {$arrayElemAt: ["$shadow", "$$this"]},
                      {$add: ["$$this", "$firstItem"]}
                  ]},
                  [{$arrayElemAt: ["$shadow", "$$this"]}],
                  []
              ]},
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {data: {$filter: {input: "$data", cond: {$in: ["$$this.key", "$shadow"]}}}}},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$project: {comment: "$data.comment", key: "$data.key"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wYpDJb3bJdZ)

Comment: Nimrod, this is cool !  thanks !
I updated the input documents and added an additional "comment" field.  How can I get it in the output too ?

Comment: It will look like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oZzHMP6_RkZ)

Comment: Nimrod, thanks for your response.  I only got now to handle it.
It looks there is a problem in your code, because it doesn't work for sequences of size =1 . I mean, it doesn't return sequences of size=1, only if it's >1.  For example in the above example: if the "key" of the first item is 9 and not 1

Comment: What is a sequence of size 1? What would be the expected results in the case you described (`key` 9 instead of 1)? I understood you want to find "the first continuous keys", meaning the pair of consecutive keys with the smallest value...

Comment: It's a matter of definition. I have just noticed that there is no need to change the original example, because even there you find sequences of length >=2.
So let me rephrase the requirement: For each user find the first group of continuous keys. For each such group return the max length of continuous keys. So if the first item has no consequent key- return only that first one.
Please note that I need only the first group per user.
I hope it's ok now

Comment: It is not clear to me. "For each user find the first group of continuous keys. For each such group return the max length of continuous keys." - I think this part is clear, but the result of it will be a group of continuous keys per user. "continuous keys" is a list of keys where each key is equal to the previous key + 1. If this is correct, the length of this list can't be 1. In order for me to understand this, please provide the requested result for the current sample, and if it is identical to the result of the current answer, please provide another example with its requested result.

Comment: Actually, now I see it works only for list size ==2. and not even when there are more documents. see https://mongoplayground.net/p/QiCFZ2t0B7p

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly